# How can I configure the Angular Language Service in IntelliJ

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

The Angular Language Service provides static code analysis: https://angular.io/guide/language-service

- How can I configure the rules?
- How can I mark certain code sections to be ignored?

Comment: Presumably you follow the same guidance as for WebStorm, also a JetBrains product. We have it in our dependencies, and get autocomplete in the templates in IntelliJ as described.

Comment: Yes, it works. But how can I configure the individual rules?
(like it is possible for tslint https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/)

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't. That documentation doesn't mention the possibility of doing so, so I don't know why you think otherwise. It doesn't really make sense to configure - which particular "rules" do you want to change?